# Knockout.js grouping lookup

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Bit new to knockout so I seem to be struggling with this grouping.

The server returns the following json

```
{"EmployeeData":[{"Id":1,"EmployeeName":"AA Guy1","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":1},{"Id":2,"EmployeeName":"BB Guy2","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":2},{"Id":3,"EmployeeName":"CC Guy3","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":2},{"Id":4,"EmployeeName":"DD Guy4","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":3},{"Id":5,"EmployeeName":"EE Guy5","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":1},{"Id":6,"EmployeeName":"FF Guy6","EmployeeNumber":1004,"Department":3}],"Dpts":[{"Id":1,"Name":"First Level Department","Desc":"1st somewhere out there"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Finance services","Desc":"Show me the money"},{"Id":3,"Name":"HR Department","Desc":"No education needed"}]}
```

I then have a table which has

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: GroupEmployees" >
    <tr class="employee-row">
    <td>
        <strong>
           <span data-bind="text: EmployeeName"></span>
        </strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text: EmployeeNumber"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text: Department" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

this showed the employee and just department number,....
I added the dpts to json, and i now have to get it to group by department. so it has to have a department heading - and under that list all employees in that department, then repeat for each department..

Im struggling to see how to get this right.

It's probably simple for somebody with more knockout experience.

Comment: Create jsfiddle demo, without it, impossible to understand the problem reason.

Comment: Hmm doubt you can do it with your json structure the way it is. Can you change that to return your employee data records within each department object?

Comment: I can return the department name in the employee records rather than the Id.

Comment: I don't think that will help - the problem is that I am not aware of any knockout instructions that will create the binding context on the fly for the grouping, if that makes sense. You will need to build that yourself, even if it is in your javascript code...

Comment: so if i add dept name , can i then use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mXVtN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see for you to achieve this is to modify your data to look like this:

```
{
  "Dpts" : [
      {
          "Name" : "Finance",
          "EmployeeData" : 
          [
             { "Id":"1", "EmployeeNumber":1001 },
             { "Id":"2", "EmployeeNumber":1002 },
             { "Id":"3", "EmployeeNumber":1003 }
          ]
      },
      {
          "Name" : "HR",
          "EmployeeData" : 
          [
             { "Id":"4", "EmployeeNumber":1004 },
             { "Id":"5", "EmployeeNumber":1005 },
             { "Id":"6", "EmployeeNumber":1006 }
          ]
      },
  ]
}
```

And then have two nested knockout "foreach"'s:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Dpts" >
<tr>
  <td>
    <strong>
       <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </strong>
  </td>
  <td>
     <table>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: EmployeeData">
       ...
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That seemed to be what I needed, Thanks.